Using test_prof before_all recipe with manual connection switching in multiple db setup
I am using test-prof gem with before_all recipe to create all the necessary records for the suite and run a heavy service afterwards.
Yet I'm running into a problem when a block of queries is executed in a separate reading role connection inside this service (there are no records that I have created prior to that):
ActiveRecord::Base.connected_to(role: :reading) do
  <...>
end

I have been trying to configure TestProf to recognize the reading role connection like this, but to no avail
TestProf::BeforeAll.configure do |config|
  config.before(:begin) do
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection_handler.connection_pool_list(:reading).each do |pool|
      pool.connection.begin_transaction(joinable: false)
    end
  end

  config.after(:rollback) do
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection_handler.connection_pool_list(:reading).each do |pool|
      pool.connection.rollback_transaction
    end
  end
end

However if I move the service call from before_all to before(:each) it works splendidly.
So basically I have two questions:
How to make it work through spec setup manipulations so I would not have to change the service code?
Why is it working well with before(:each) and not with before_all? For some reason, ActiveRecord::Base.connected_to(role: :reading) has different config in before(:each) (replica is missing, target_session_attrs: 'read-write') rather than in before_all (replica: true, target_session_attrs: 'any').
